# connecting dialogflow to mysql database for inserting data into mysql tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
const functions = require( 'firebase-functions' );
const mysql = require( 'mysql' );
const {WebhookClient} = require( 'dialogflow-fulfillment' );
const {Text, Card, Image, Suggestion, Payload} = require( 'dialogflow-fulfillment' );

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

const mysiteurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narendra_Modi';


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest( ( request, response ) =>{
  const agent = new WebhookClient( {request, response} );
  console.log( 'Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify( request.headers ) );
  console.log( 'Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify( request.body ) );

  let action = request.body.result['action'];
 function welcome( agent ){
    agent.add( `Welcome to infohub personal assistant, my name is Isobel` );
    agent.add( new Card( {
        title: `mysite`,
        imageUrl: mysiteurl,
        text: `Did you know already mysite if not visit it now! `,
        buttonText: 'mysite',
        buttonUrl: mysiteurl
      } )
    );
    agent.add( `I can help you get information already contained in mysite` );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `population` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `avgincome` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `thisyeargdp` ) );
  }


      //Call the callDBJokes method

function navigationdistance( agent ){
    // Get parameters from Dialogflow to convert
    const from = agent.parameters.from;
    const to = agent.parameters.to;
    console.log( `User requested to get info on  ${to} in ${from}` );


    if (action === 'get.data') {

        // Call the callDBJokes method
        callDB().then((output) => {
            // Return the results of the weather API to API.AI
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.send(JSON.stringify(output));
        }).catch((error) => {
            // If there is an error let the user know
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.send(JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    }


    // Sent the context to store the parameter information
    // and make sure the followup 
    agent.setContext( {
      name: 'navigationdistance',
      lifespan: 3,
      parameters: {from: from, to: to}
    } );

    // Compile and send response
    agent.add( ` ${to} in ${from} ` );

    agent.add( `Would you like to know something else?` );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `population` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `avgincome` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `thisyeargdp` ) );
  }




  function fallback( agent ){
    agent.add( `I didnt get that, can you try again?` );
  }

  function callDB( to, from ){
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{

        try{

          var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "",
            database: "test"
          } );

          var sql = "INSERT INTO mocktable (from, to) VALUES ('$from', '$to')";
          connection.query( sql, function( error, results, fields ){
            if( !error ){

              let response = "The solution is: " + results[0];
              response = response.toString();
              let output = {'speech': response, 'displayText': response};
              console.log( output );
              resolve( output );

            } else{

              let output = {
                'speech': 'Error. Query Failed.',
                'displayText': 'Error. Query Failed.'
              };
              console.log( output );
              reject( output );

            }
          } );
          connection.end();

        } catch
          ( err ){
          let output = {
            'speech': 'try-cacth block error',
            'displayText': 'try-cacth block error'
          };
          console.log( output );
          reject( output );

        }

    });
  }



  let intentMap = new Map(); // Map functions to Dialogflow intent names
  intentMap.set( 'Default Welcome Intent', welcome );
  intentMap.set( 'get info about mycountry', navigationdistance );
  intentMap.set( 'Default Fallback Intent', fallback );
  agent.handleRequest( intentMap );
})
;
```

This is the code I'm using to connect dialogflow to the database. I'm using the inline editor in dialogflow and modifying it to connect it to a database. I'm unable to connect to the database . Is there any other method to connect dialogflow to a database.

1. I have all the dependencies in the package.json file.
2. I have created a database named test in MySQL.
3. I have created some intents in dialogflow and I'm getting the default responses from the intents.
4. I need to insert the details from the response to the database.

TIA,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running the MySQL database on your local machine and trying to reach it via the host name "localhost". There are a few problems doing this with the Dialogflow built-in code editor:

- Dialogflow does not run that fulfillment code on your local machine. It runs it using Firebase Cloud Functions.
- Since the code isn't running on your local machine, calling "localhost" calls the machine it is running on. Which, since it is a Google machine, doesn't have MySQL running on it. (And certainly not one with that account and password!)
- But even if you *did* give it the name of a machine that was publicly accessible, Firebase Cloud Functions has restrictions on accessing machines outside Google's cloud. You can get access by upgrading to a paid account (which includes a free tier).

You have a few possible approaches to addressing this:

- Instead of using the built-in editor, you could run your fulfillment code on the same machine where you're running MySQL (or any machine with a secure, public, URL).

  - If you don't have a public URL, you can use a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [serveo.net](http://serveo.net/) to create a tunnel to your local server
- You could use [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) service, which can be a managed MySQL instance. (You may still need to setup billing for your project, however there are credits available to get started, and when you publish your action, you're eligible for additional credits.)
- You could move to something like [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), which is a no-SQL database, but more than suitable for key-value storage. (But, again, may require setting up billing.)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the Firestore database if I were you. Free and is a Google product anyways! https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart